# Unable to read the contents of this file system, required for ntfs file system support: ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g, gparted

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, ntfs

In my brother's single boot Ubuntu PC, I was trying to resize `/dev/sda5` partition with gparted, which is in ntfs format, but found a warning, that showing—

> Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this some operations may be unavailable. The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of of software packages is required for ntfs file system support: ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g.

I have installed `ntfs-3g` and `ntfs-config` packages and tried to fix the partition with `ntfs-fix`. But it is not worked, a warning sign is showing yet.

What can I do now?

Comment: I have the same problem for exfat and f2fs even though the required tools are installed

Answer (score 2):

You've probably found a solution by now, but if not, could you put the drive in a PC with windows and try running chkdsk /f? I had a similar error and was able to fix it that way.

Also running the following command may give some insight into what the issue is:

```
ntfsresize --info --force --no-progress-bar /your-partition
```