# 22.04 not mounting NTFS flash drive (not "Fast Boot" issue)

Tags: usb, 22.04, usb-drive, ntfs

The damn 22.04 won't let me use the usb drive.

It is not the usb drive as it works fine in a Windows machine. It is formatted as ntfs:
[image]

As per this answer ([Ubuntu 20.04 Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236397/ubuntu-20-04-error-mounting-dev-sdb1-at-media)) I ran `sudo apt install --reinstall ntfs-3g`. installing an NTFS driver will fix it right? Didn't work.

As per this answer ([Unable to Mount NTFS Drives after upgrading to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405882/unable-to-mount-ntfs-drives-after-upgrading-to-22-04)) I thought I was missing fuse. I ran `sudo apt install fuse`. Nope. WTF.

The O/S is new. I noticed all the answers on this topic were dual boot. Mine is too, but that's maybe because anywhere you get windows you get NTFS. I dunno. Anyway I installed gparted during this adventure, and here is the message:

[image]

I obviously ran all the updates. I'm a simpleton who just wants open some files. Any advice?

Thanks ;-)

***********************UPDATE**************************

Thank you for alerting me to the "Fast Boot" option in windows in the comments. It was a really good suggestion as the USB does work in Windows. However I don't think this is applicable. All my windows computers are Windows 7; and apparently this "fast boot" windows option is a windows 8 and up (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-turn-off-fast-startup-or-quick-boot-in/618cd53a-7c53-42a3-989c-00b721af1bf6).

The PC used to be 18.04 and the USB was working fine. Then I installed Ubuntu 22.04, and now it won't work; and I didn't touch the BIOS during the install, so it's not any Bios settings/parameters/values (i don't know the right word), it's not the USB (as in it's not a dead USB), and windows reads it no problem.

Any help is appreciated. For some reason someone downvoted this question, so let's continue the trend... can you please down vote as well? I would love to see how low a decent question can get. Thanks!

Comment: You have last used the USB key on a Windows system with "Fast Boot " turned on. This causes Windows to make the USB key look funny. Take it back to Windows, turn off "Fast Boot", then it will wirk on Linux.

Comment: Reinstalling `ntfs-3g` or another package is unlikely to do anything. Besides, 22.04 should use the new NTFS3 kernel module. Also, you install updates, not run them.

Comment: @waltinator according to this page (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-turn-off-fast-startup-or-quick-boot-in/618cd53a-7c53-42a3-989c-00b721af1bf6) fast boot is a windows 8 and up. All my windows are 7. The PC hardware is the same, so it's not a bios thing. It's the 22.04. Any other ideas? Thanks bro.

Comment: @mikewhatever You seem to have an in-depth understanding. That's great! Can you suggest what will work? It's not a "fast boot" option issue. Kindly see the comment I just put up. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this Linux issue... apparently you need Windows! LOL.

In the comments, it was suggested to disable a windows feature. In this answer ([Unable to read the contents of this file system, required for ntfs file system support: ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g, gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969223/unable-to-read-the-contents-of-this-file-system-required-for-ntfs-file-system-s)) it was suggested to run a windows diagnostic when Linux falls short... OF WINDOWS???!!!

The solution for this issue that worked for me was to go to Windows, and to go "Computer Management" and to run a disk check with "Automatically fix the system errors" option selected: [image]

How do we need Windows to fix our Linux issues?! I understand that people are helping each other resolve problems here, but I don't this that a solution to a Linux issue that relies on Windows is "OK".

Comment: NTFS is not a Linux native format. It is a Windows format. Microsoft does not make all the tools it has for managing and fixing NTFS open source and available in Linux. If you don't want to depend on Windows, don't use NTFS.

Comment: @user68186 I learned something new. THank you. So Linux doesn't have the tools to fix these issue? if so, I'll accept this answer to the question I asked.

Comment: Postmortem: It looks like you had a few wrong assumtions, which led to wrong expectations, and also to wrong conclusions - a kind of rabit hole I'd want to avoid. It is perfectly obvious that what you call "linux" is not perfect, and doesn't have solutions for everything.