# How to fix NTFS formatted hardware

Tags: gparted, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I just recovered from an issue here: [22.04 not mounting NTFS flash drive (not "Fast Boot" issue)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1485979/22-04-not-mounting-ntfs-flash-drive-not-fast-boot-issue)

Many of the answers/comments on this website related to the issue I experienced, had to some degree suggested use of Windows. WTF?

Can some Linux guru please show how to:

1. use Linux to fix NTFS file system errors? The windows equivalent of how I solved my issue in the answer I provided.
2. Show how to tease out the symptoms that would lead you to fixing the NTFS file system? I mean, when would you know that the solution you just provided in first bullet is appropriate.

I love Linux, and it hurts to see this issue rely on Windows to fix a Linux "challenge".

Thanks.

*****EDIT******
`ntfsfix` was suggested in the comments. during my issue, I saw that used here: [Unable to read the contents of this file system, required for ntfs file system support: ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g, gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969223/unable-to-read-the-contents-of-this-file-system-required-for-ntfs-file-system-s)

However I couldn't install it and there was no manual entry for it:
[image]

Comment: Use ntfsfix for that.

Comment: @nobody see edit.

Comment: NTFS is a proprietary filesystem. Microsoft (who owns NTFS) does not publish the full specifications for NTFS. Linux support of NTFS is limited by the lack of documentation.  It's not Linux's fault.

Comment: @Mike answer is in your other question why that is wrong. See the 2nd image there. "nobody" is correct. Plus why the aggressive tone? if you use NTFS you will need windows at some point. repairing windows filesystems should be done using windows tools. From another OS a fix is NOT a fix but a patch: ntfsfix for instance removes the windows hibersys file. That in itself might mean you delete windows data not saved on disk. That could include data you did not want to delete

Comment: Try `man 8 ntfsfix`. Or look here: [man 8 ntfsfix](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-ntfsfix/)

Comment: The `ntfsfix`-command is part of the package `ntfs-3g`. `ntfsfix` can fix some common problems. It is not a replacement for the `chkdsk`-command from Windows. Install the `ntfs-3g`-package and then read the man pages `man ntfsfix`.